# Counting the numer of occurrences of a certain value in a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I have a DataFrame in the form of this picture:[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XooU8.png)

I am trying to create a new column that would have a count of the times that each individual Administrative port showed in the dataset.[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeTEe.png)

An idea I tried was to create a new DataFrame with each unique port as a row. Then iterate over each row and feed the value of each row into `.value_counts` as so.

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    df1['count'] = df1.value_counts().df2.row['Administrative port']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Series.map`:

```
df1['count'] = df1['Administrative port'].map(df1['Administrative port'].value_counts())
```